# Rest WebService client Jersey XML data

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am trying to consume a rest web service via jersey api. Here is the code:

RestClient.java

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;


public class RestClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {                       
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/rest/UserService/users");
            ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);

            if(response.getStatus() == 200)
            {
                System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Error : " + response.getStatus());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><users><user><id>1</id><name>Mahesh</name><profession>Scientist</profession></user></users>
```

I am getting the response in XML format. I would like to know that if there is a way in jersey api, so that web get the data plain text format?

Comment: You can use `text/plain` instead `application/xml`

Comment: Then it would be difficult to differentiate the data i.e. id, name, profession.

Comment: You are asking to get the data in plain text format so I am saying it. You can use `application/json` that returns in json format which is key - value pair. You can easily identify the data.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want this data in text format? I mean there are ways you can specify how the API Produces the result like text/json/etc. But in the end, how would you want the data to be presented? Because text format for objects may not be a good option.

Comment: What even *is* text format? The media-type "text/plain" doesn't even tell you how the data is structured within the response. XML *is* a text format, as is JSON. So the question really is how do you want your data structured?